# exec with customization string in python3

Tags: python-3.x, class, exec, customization

I want to generate the object that the user can input the variable name, but I have no idea why Nameerror happens when I do with the following code:

```
class Layer: 
    def __init__(self,Diameter,Thickness,Porosity,Name):
        self.d = Diameter
        self.t = Thickness
        self.phi = Porosity
        self.name = Name
    
Name = input('Name of the layer:    ')
d1 = 1
d2 = 2
d3 = 3
exec('%s = Layer(%d,%d,%d,%s)'%(Name,d1,d2,d3,Name))
```

If I have the input like

```
Name of the layer:    Trial
```

Then it comes to the error like:

```
NameError: name 'Trial' is not defined
```

I have tried some other ways like:

```
class Layer:

    def __init__(self,Diameter,Thickness,Porosity,Name):
        self.d = Diameter
        self.t = Thickness
        self.phi = Porosity
        self.name = Name
        
Name = input('Name of the layer:    ')
name = Name
d1 = 1
d2 = 2
d3 = 3
exec('%s = Layer(%d,%d,%d,%s)'%(Name,d1,d2,d3,name))
```

Even something like this fail:

```
class Layer
    def __init__(self,Diameter,Thickness,Porosity,Name):
        self.d = Diameter
        self.t = Thickness
        self.phi = Porosity
        self.name = Name
    
Name = input('Name of the layer:    ')
name = 'Trial2'
d1 = 1
d2 = 2
d3 = 3
exec('%s = Layer(%d,%d,%d,%s)'%(Name,d1,d2,d3,name))
```

And returned `NameError: name 'Trial2' is not defined`

However, if I removed `name', like the following:

```
class Layer:

def __init__(self,Diameter,Thickness,Porosity):
    self.d = Diameter
    self.t = Thickness
    self.phi = Porosity
    self.name = Name
    
Name = input('Name of the layer:    ')
d1 = 1
d2 = 2
d3 = 3
exec('%s = Layer(%d,%d,%d)'%(Name,d1,d2,d3))
```

The object can be generated. But it then lost the properties `name`.

Comment: Try printing out the string you want to execute. If that doesn't tell you what's wrong with it, copy it into an interactive Python shell.

Comment: exec('%s = Layer(%d,%d,%d,%s)'%(Name,d1,d2,d3,Name)) . In this line you had used Name variable 2 times. In first it is "%d" and you are giving name (string)

Comment: Hi Brian, if your question is answered and clear to you, please consider [accepting or upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `exec` with `print` gives a hint of what's wrong:

```py
print('%s = Layer(%d,%d,%d,%s)'%(Name,d1,d2,d3,Name))
```

gives

```py
Trial = Layer(1,2,3,Trial)
                    ^^^^^ here is the problem
```

but what you actually need is

```py
Trial = Layer(1,2,3,"Trial")
```

because the last argument should be a string. Otherwise, Python will look for a variable named `Trial`, cannot find one and thus raises a `NameError`. Translated back to your code, this means adding quotes around the second occurrence of `Name`:

```py
exec('%s = Layer(%d,%d,%d,"%s")'%(Name,d1,d2,d3,Name))
```

The reason for this is that although `Name` is a string, you use it to create a code snippet with it. This snippet has to be valid Python syntax which requires the addition of quotes. The original type of `Name` disappears once you pass it into the string formatting.

Comment: But then how do I correct it? I have tried to use `str(Name)'.

Comment: The most weird place is that why the first Name is fine but the second one does not...

Comment: Because the first `Trial` is the name of the variable you're defining whereas the second `Trial` is supposed to be a string.

Comment: Thank you, I have found the correct way to fix it now. It is to add the quotation mark in the last 'name'.

Comment: yes, I just added that to the answer to make it clear. Is the reason for the problem and its solution clear to you?

Comment: I might want to ask the reason why I have to add a quotation mark for the last one. In my understanding, the Name variable should already be a string, just like d1 d2 d3 are float. Isn't it Name is a string object with value 'Trial'?

Comment: It's because you create another string with it (the code snippet) which doesn't know its original type. However, that code snippet needs to follow Python's syntax rules which means strings have to be surrounded by quotes. I extended my answer.